# Is this terminal error due to lack of directory?

Tags: php, apache, terminal

When running a terminal command:

```
$/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.2.17/bin/php push.php development
```

A terminal error is displayed

```
zsh: no such file or directory: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.2.17/bin/php
```

The Mac doesn't have a php5.2.17 folder as the terminal command is from an older project.`. Currently these are the folders there today.

[image]

Which folder name should be substituted for the folder named `php5.2.17` in the terminal command path?

**Update**

When replacing the `php5.2.17` path with `php5.4.45` or any of the other folder names in the `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/` directory the terminal displays an error of

```
Could not open input file: push.php
```

Comment: Does `push.php` exists in the directory where you run this?

Comment: No it does no. I found that odd. as well...

Comment: If you want to run a php script, you need to actually have a php script =)

Comment: Ty for the response. After copying and pasting `push.php` into the path `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.2.17/bin/php` the terminal still says `Could not open input file: push.php`

Comment: The file needs to be in the current directory, not the same directory as the php binary.

Comment: or just specify a full path `/Application/blablabla/php /path/to/push.php`

Comment: @Evert appreciate you. I copied the push.php file as well as the required pem file into the terminal path using folder `php7.4.2` and it seems to have started the cron job like process

Comment: I still find it odd that the development log says that the connection to APNS was successful now, even though the only way the command is successfully running right now is if I first change directories using the terminal to the path where the `push.php` file exists and then run the original command with the new path `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.2/bin/php push.php development `

Comment: If you got both the working directory right and the path to the PHP binary is right, and it works, why is this odd to you?